# How to setup a golang app config according to the environment using yaml file

Tags: go, yaml

Im trying to setup a config struct to use through my application.

Currently I load a yaml file and decode it in my config struct.

###### `config.yml`

```yaml
  database_url: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/database_dev
```

###### `config.go`

```golang
import (
  "os"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type AppConfig struct {
  DatabaseUrl      string `yaml:"database_url"`
}

func LoadConfig() *AppConfig {
  appConfig := &AppConfig{}
  file, _ := os.Open("config.yml")
  defer f.Close()
  decoder := yaml.NewDecoder(file)
  decoder.Decode(config)
  return appConfig
}
```

It works really fine, but now I need to setup different configuration according with the environment (test, local, production, etc.).

I thought that I could use a nested yaml file to declare the environments variables.

###### `config.yml`

```yaml
dev:
  database_url: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/database_dev
test:
  database_url: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/database_test
```

I would like to receive the environment as a parameter in my `LoadConfig` function, and get the correct configuration.
But I have no idea how to.

###### `config.go`

```golang
type configFile struct {
  Dev struct { AppConfig }`yaml:"dev"`
  Test struct { AppConfig }`yaml:"test"` 
}

func LoadConfig(env string) *AppConfig {
  appConfig := &AppConfig{}
  configFile := &configFile{}
  file, _ := os.Open("config.yml")
  defer f.Close()
  decoder := yaml.NewDecoder(file)
  decoder.Decode(configFile)
  
  // How to get the correct struct here ?
  // config = configFile["env"]
  // It doesn't works 
  // invalid operation: cannot index configFile (variable of type *configFile)


  return appConfig
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list of environments is arbitrary, then you don't want a `struct` for the top level; you want a `map[string]AppConfig`. That would look something like this:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"

  "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type (
  AppConfig struct {
    DatabaseUrl string `yaml:"database_url"`
  }

  ConfigFile map[string]*AppConfig
)

func LoadConfig(env string) (*AppConfig, error) {
  configFile := ConfigFile{}
  file, _ := os.Open("config.yml")
  defer file.Close()
  decoder := yaml.NewDecoder(file)

  // Always check for errors!
  if err := decoder.Decode(&configFile); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }

  appConfig, ok := configFile[env]
  if !ok {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("no such environment: %s", env)
  }

  return appConfig, nil
}

func main() {
  appConfig, err := LoadConfig(os.Args[1])
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("config: %+v\n", appConfig)
}
```

Assuming we have the `config.yml` from your question, we can run the above example with different environments and see the desired output:

```
$ ./example test
config: &{DatabaseUrl:postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/database_test}
$ ./example dev
config: &{DatabaseUrl:postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/database_dev}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think one way is that we can different config files for different environments. For example, in dev environment we have `config_dev.yaml`, in production, we have `config_prod.yaml`.

Then we specify environment variable in the bootstrap scripts. For example we run the app by `export MyEnv=dev && ./my_app`. In the code, we check `MyEnv` to decide which config file we would use. In this case, we found MyEnv is `dev` so we use `config_dev.yaml`.